# Ошибка при первом запуске на хостинге. Сайт на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Разместил сайт на популярном таймхостинге, и сразу же появилась ошибка: `The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему? Может кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Подключаюсь по SSH, пытаюсь обновить APP_KEY с помощью `php artisan key:generate` - вываливается ошибка: 
`PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or 'S' in /home/c/логин/domain.ru/artisan on line 31`

Версия Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказано на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693312/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key), что вам требуется **.env** в вашем сайте.

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

Если у вас отсутствует **.env** скопируйте с **.env.example:**

```
$ cp .env.example .env
```

Проверьте длину ключа. Длина не должна превышать 16 символов при AES-128 или 32 символа при AES-256.

Ошибка `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or 'S' in /home/c/логин/domain.ru/artisan on line 31` сообщает о том, что установленная версия PHP не поддерживает данную функцию. Для исправления ошибки требуется обновить PHP на стороне сервера.

Comment: Хм...но там есть файл .env, и более того APP_KEY тоже не пуст

Comment: Посмотри длину ключа. Длина ключа должна быть у AES-128 = 16 символов, а у AES-256 = 32.

Comment: Установлено AES-256, и длина ключа превышает 32. Но как быть в таком случае? Ключ генерировал командой php artisan key:generate

Comment: Бывает оно генерирует ключ с двумя `base64:` удали один и это должно исправить ситуацию.

Comment: А можно на примере? APP_KEY=base64:XFQD6ZLjoljX5obKDK8sjD5u9mUQjoLerQer0RWPaBw= что тут удалить надо?)

Comment: Попробуй `php artisan config:clear` и `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74967/discussion-between-yurigo-and-tivyram).